# Launch Angular SPA application from ASP.net Core MVC controller after Identity Server authorization

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using (Duende) Identity Server to Authorize users, upon successful authorization the user is redirect to an Angular SPA application.

1. The home page presents the user with a login screen (username / Password).
2. The home page posts to LoginController that has an Authorize attribute on the login Action method that is HttpPost. The Authorize call the Duende Authorization server to verify.
3. IF successful, the Identity server redirects to {our domain}/signin-oidc
4. **Question** Signin-oidc should this be an Action Method on a controller or in the Angular SPA. Is this an internal call within the Identity server ? Where does the Sign-oidc method exist ?
5. Right now the call returns to the same Login action but as HttpGet
6. IF the user is Authenticated, the Action method redirects to a new Controller and action that essentially launches the Angular SPA ?
7. **QUESTION** is this approach correct ?
8. **Question** :should the Angular SPA be calling the Identity Server directly using an OIDC Client ?
9. When a user logs out, is the ASP.net Core MVC application aware of the user as Authenticated or not ?
10. **Question** there is also a signout-callback-oidc --> where does this exist ?